# Adding section of one list to another list

Tags: c#, .net

I have a two lists, A & B. B contains say 100 elements. How do I add the 20th - 30th elements to list A from B. I know there is the AddRange but to me that looks like it would add all the elements from list B to list A. Is there a way to do this without using a loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming both lists have the same underlying type, you can use LINQ's [`Skip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`Take()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) methods to get the range of items you want from the second list:

```
var a = new List<string>();
// add 100 elements to a

var b = new List<string>();
// add 100 elements to b

a.AddRange(b.Skip(19).Take(11));  // add items 20 through 30 from b to a
```

Comment: As a side note, `Skip/Take` is apparently less performant for larger collections than `GetRange` (http://icodeit.wordpress.com/2012/08/27/performance-of-skip-and-take-in-linq-to-objects/). Not relevant to this post as OP only has a couple of hundred elements but just something for people to consider if using larger sets.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`GetRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) To get the elements from List A and then [`AddRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to add the elements to List B if they are of same type.

For example:

```
        List<int> a = new List<int>();
        List<int> b = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            b.Add(i);
        }
        List<int> sublist = a.GetRange(20, 10);
        a.AddRange(sublist);
```

Comment: GetRange() is specific to `List<>`. Skip & Take work on the more general `IEnumerable<>`